# Call controller function of SAP UI5 using jQuery

Tags: jquery, sapui5

Is there any way to call SAP UI5 controller function inside an jQuery syntax written inside init() function of controller?
What I meant is I have written below code snippet inside init() of user.controller.js. I have a function  checkId() written inside that same controller which I want to call in the below snippet.How to do that?
My code:

```
    $(window).load(function(){
       $("#myid").mousedown(function(){
         this.checkId(); //returns is not a function
       });
    });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very closely related to the way in which the `this` keyword works in JavaScript. Check out [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) for more details.

You have three different possibilities to overcome the issues that you face:

1) Alias the `this` (store it into a variable):

```
var oController = this;
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#myid").mousedown(function(){
         oController.checkId();
    });
});
```

2) Rebind the `this` context for your inner functions (using e.g. `.bind` or `jQuery.proxy`):

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#myid").mousedown(function(){
         this.checkId();
    }.bind(this));
}.bind(this));
```

3) Use [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (if you don't face problems related to browser support or if you have a transpilation build setup):

```
$(window).load(() => $("#myid").mousedown(() => this.checkId()));
```

Also, you should avoid as much as possible to manually add DOM event handlers in UI5. You could simply use a UI5 button and attach your method to the UI5 `press` event instead.